# Blocking background applications from receiving messages

Tags: c++, winapi, message-queue

I'm trying to block a background application from receiving mouse events. Despite making sure that the message target's handle matches the foreground window, the background application still receives my mouse events if I hover over it.

I've also tried hooking WH_MOUSE_LL but the MSLLHOOKSTRUCT just doesn't seem to provide sufficient information to filter them.

```
MSG msg = {0};
while(GetMessage(&msg, reinterpret_cast<HWND>(-1), 0, 0) > 0)
{
    if (msg.hwnd == GetForegroundWindow())
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

I expected the background window to not receive any events as long as it was in the background.

Comment: `GetMessage` will only return messages to windows in the current thread.  It cannot be used to intercept messages intended for another process.

Answer (score 0):

For mouse messages in particular, there is a solution.

The foreground window can call `SetCapture` and then all subsequent mouse messages will be delivered to it, even if outside its bounds.